# Flutter app crash with appbunddle but works with apk

Tags: flutter

Everything's working fine with the apk but when deploy on the playstore I had to create an appbundle (.aab), I can download the app from the playstore but it crash when I try to open it

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
 
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
        body: WebViewLoad()
       )
      );
  }
}

class WebViewLoad extends StatefulWidget {

  WebViewLoadUI createState() => WebViewLoadUI();

}

class WebViewLoadUI extends State<WebViewLoad>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 0,
        ),
    body: WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://www.google.fr',
      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,

    )
  );
  }
}
```

I ran this command to create the appbuild

```
flutter build appbuild --release --no-sound-null-safety
```

Any idea of what it doesn't work?

Comment: what is the crash? post stacktrace of crash.

Comment: I download my app from the playstore and had this error 'myapp s'arrête systématiquement' not sure about the translation in english, can be 'myapp stop systematicaly'. How can I have the stacktrace ?

Comment: Did you try to run app in `release` build locally? `flutter run --release`? You are using Crashlytics or similar bug tracker?